# How can I stop file contents being displayed in Windows 7 explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

These file contents details have started being displayed when I search for files in Windows 7.

[image: File Contents Example Image]

I've looked through folder options and can't find anything that stops them being displayed. I'd prefer to keep the display type setting I have, as they never used to appear.

Hopefully there is some setting hidden somewhere or a registry key I can change that someone knows of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the view to details or whatever you like.

Click the view button in the Explorer menubar.
[image: image view symbol]

or,
rightclick (on an empty space between the files, not on a file)
and choose “View” and select the desired view.
        [image: “View” submenu]

---

**Edit:** *for contentview without content*

I created a text file with random content and searched for it. The search result contained the content of the file.
[screeenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZNio.png)

To have content view without showing the content, I removed the indexing option for the User folder (and for subfolder and files when it asked). This should work too if you only remove the indexing for my documents if the files are in this folder. 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtzhN.png)

Then I edited the folder search options to only search content for indexed files.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q72Js.png)

Now, if I search for the file, the content is not displayed anymore in the result.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1GXe.png)

Comment: Thanks Manuel. However I'm looking for a way to have the file contents not displayed while in the view I am in, as they never used to display from within this view.

Comment: You want the content view without content? I think this might be possible if you disable the file indexing in the advanced folder attributes. and set the "what to search" in the search tab of the folder options to: _In indexed Locations, search file names and contents. In non-indexed locations, search file names only._

Comment: I have tested it and it worked for me. see edit to my answer.